# How this SQL Query in hbm.xml file can be written in source code?

Tags: sql, hibernate, hql

I am trying to run a SQL query in Hibernate. I am using its [documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core/reference/en/html/querysql.html#d0e14492).
Because of some unknown values i am trying to do inside the Source code.

See this below SQL-Query configuration. How to re-write it in source code itself!!
I tried this

`personList = session.createSQLQuery("SELECT person.NAME, person.AGE, person.SEX, address.STREET, address.CITY, address.STATE, address.ZIP FROM person JOIN address WHERE person.ID = address.PERSON_ID").addEntity(Person.class).addEntity(Address.class).list();`

What i am trying to do with the above query is, it should map person.ID & PERSON_ID. If it matches, then fetch the other columns in the ADDRESS[STREET, CITY, STATE, ZIP] table with the PERSON table columns[NAME, AGE, SEX].

In JDBC the columns of resultset, for the above query looks like

`NAME, AGE, SEX, STREET, CITY, STATE, ZIP`

But its not working it says, address columns in the query were not found. Is there any syntax error in my version of query!!

**Query Declaration in mapping file**;

```
<sql-query name="personsWith">
<return alias="person" class="eg.Person"/>
<return-join alias="address" property="person.mailingAddress"/>
SELECT person.NAME AS {person.name},
       person.AGE AS {person.age},
       person.SEX AS {person.sex},
       address.STREET AS {address.street},
       address.CITY AS {address.city},
       address.STATE AS {address.state},
       address.ZIP AS {address.zip}
FROM PERSON person
JOIN ADDRESS address
    ON person.ID = address.PERSON_ID
</sql-query>
```

Thanks

Comment: What do you really want to achieve? Are you sure that you need this kind of optimized query? A simple query on person or address is not sufficient?

Comment: @Stefan: Actually, i want to show all the persons with address info in the address table.

Comment: I'm quite sure that you could do this in a trivial way. See my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two posible causes for not finding the `address` columns:

First, in SQL you have to write the name of the table, not the entity name.

Second, your JOIN sentence could be invalid at SQL. There are a few ways to implement a join. I'll take the direct approach (select from both table and stating the join at the where clause).

Suposing that the `person` entity maps a table called "`TABLE_PERSON`", and `address` maps table "`TABLE_ADDRESS`", a valid query would look as follows:

```
SELECT person.NAME, person.AGE, person.SEX, 
     address.STREET, address.CITY, address.STATE, address.ZIP 
FROM TABLE_PERSON person, TABLE_ADDRESS address 
WHERE person.ID = address.PERSON_ID
```

One more point. Checking the hibernate documentation, I have found this example:

```
List cats = sess.createSQLQuery("select {cat.*}, {kitten.*} from cats cat, cats kitten 
where kitten.mother = cat.id").
     setResultSetMapping("catAndKitten").list();
```

So, maybe the problem is not at the query itself, but on the resultSet Mapping you are using, and the way to reference the fields.

Let's suppose this mapping (from the Hibernate doc):

```
<resultset name="personAddress">
    <return alias="person" class="eg.Person"/>
    <return-join alias="address" property="person.mailingAddress"/>
</resultset>
```

Then, as the exaple states, your query should define the columns between curly brackets (`{}`), and using the alias you have defined at the mapping:

```
personList = session.createSQLQuery(
             "SELECT {person.NAME}, {person.AGE}, {person.SEX}, "+
            "{address.STREET}, {address.CITY}, {address.STATE}, {address.ZIP} "+
            "FROM TABLE_PERSON person, TABLE_ADDRESS address "
            "WHERE person.ID = address.PERSON_ID"
        ).setResultSetMapping("personAddress")
         .list();
```

Please, tell me if any of this examples works.

Comment: I have updated my question, and explained more. Pls take a look at it.

Comment: @Code 'N' Weed: have you tried with a resultset Mapping and the curly brackets, as my last example?

Comment: Ya, tried. It ends with syntax error in SQL query :(  It says 
"use right syntax to use near ' , , , ,  FROM PERSONS person, ADDR address 
WHERE person.ID = address.PERSON_ID... "
But your previous version of query runs well in myqsl query browser.

Comment: The first version is pure SQL. The second version is to be integrated at the session.createSQLQuery Hibernate method. I should have been clearer. Will edit the example.

Answer (score 2):

It does not work because of your misuse of `AddEntity`:

This piece of code:

```
personList = session
  .createSQLQuery("SELECT ...")
  .addEntity(Person.class)
  .addEntity(Address.class).list();
```

`addEntity` does add a parameter to the query, of an entity type. For instance, you could do this:

```
personList = session
  .createSQLQuery("from person where address = :address"
  .addEntity("address", myAddess);
```

I'm not sure if you could do the same entity mapping in code. I had to read the documentation.

---

**Edit**:

You could easily find all the persons with addresses like this:

```
session.createQuery("from Person p where p.address is not null");
```

or, if there isn't an `adress` property on person:

```
session.createQuery("select distinct a.Person from Address");
```

assumed that you could have several persons on the same address.

Comment: I have updated my question, and explained more. Pls take a look at it.